# External monitor no signal ThinkPad P1

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I've used Ubuntu on my Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 2 and it works fine with the internal display. When I connect an AOC monitor with hdmi, the monitor says "no signal".

- My display settings look like this:

[image: screenshot]

- Command `xrandr` returns this:

  ```
  Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
  eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
     1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
     1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
     1600x1024     60.17  
     1400x1050     59.98  
     1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
     1280x1024     60.02  
     1440x900      59.89  
     1400x900      59.96    59.88  
     1280x960      60.00  
     1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
     1360x768      59.80    59.96  
     1280x800      59.81    59.91  
     1152x864      60.00  
     1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
     1024x768      60.00  
     1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
     960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
     800x600       60.32    56.25  
     864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
     640x480       59.94  
     720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
     640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
  VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  ```

I noticed there is a function key that looks like a laptop with a screen beside it, which should "switch between the computer display and an external monitor" but after pressing the button multiple times nothing noticable happens and the settings and outputs remain the same.

I really just want to use multiple monitors.
If you need any more info I'll be happy to provide it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to press that button while holding the Fn key